# How can I create a conditional text column in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In a Pandas Dataframe `vinhos` I have a (quite long) text column `regiao`. I want to create a new column `reg` with all the elements of another Dataframe `local` column `nome` that are found in `regiao`. I am using this code

```
local['nome']
0, Vinho Verde
1, Minho
...
4, Douro
5, Porto

vinhos['regiao']
...
232, Douro tinto 2014
...

vinhos['reg']
Douro
```

`vinhos['reg'] = ','.join([r for r in local['nome'] if r in vinhos['regiao']])`

and it reurns empty column when there are elements there.

Could you help me?

Comment: Please explain your problem with sample input and expected output.

Comment: I've added some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with `word boundary` + [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
print (vinhos)
                    regiao
232       Douro tinto 2014
233  Vinho Verde Douro new

pat = '|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(x) for x in local['nome'].tolist()])
vinhos['reg'] = vinhos['regiao'].str.findall(pat).str.join(',')
print (vinhos)
                    regiao                reg
232       Douro tinto 2014              Douro
233  Vinho Verde Douro new  Vinho Verde,Douro
```